как декомпелировать файл pyc версии 3.10
Хочу депилировать несколько файлов рус, не выходит что делать
    Unsupported Python version, 3.10.0, for decompilation


# Unsupported bytecode in file __init__.cpython-310.pyc
# Unsupported Python version, 3.10.0, for decompilation
__init__.cpython-310.pyc -- decompiled 0 files: 0 okay, 0 failed


Так депилировать или декомпелировать? Это разные вещи..

сам нашёл решение как получить исходник.
https://github.com/extremecoders-re/decompyle-builds
https://youtu.be/RTsMgC36xMU?si=cEnLzmYshSnvk6mk

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.
